# Hide tr and td using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want hide tr and some td on click on a tag, I have made a function which is not hiding last tr, now i want to hide 1,2,3 and only 4 and i want to show 5,4a and 4b. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hvFRY/)

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('a').click(function(){
$('tr').not(':last').hide()
})
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table width="664" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4</td>
<td>4a</td>
<td>4b</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>5</td>
</tr>
</table>
<a href="#">hide</a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('tr').not(':last').find('td:first').hide()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hvFRY/2/